# Why __nmi_enter() defined __preempt_count_add(NMI_OFFSET + HARDIRQ_OFFSET);

Tags: linux, interrupt, nmi

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/hardirq.h#L120

```
#define __nmi_enter()                       \
    do {                            \
        lockdep_off();                  \
        arch_nmi_enter();               \
        BUG_ON(in_nmi() == NMI_MASK);           \
        __preempt_count_add(NMI_OFFSET + HARDIRQ_OFFSET);   \
    } while (0)
```

Why `enter_nmi` is:

```
__preempt_count_add(NMI_OFFSET + HARDIRQ_OFFSET);
```

why not just:

```
__preempt_count_add(NMI_OFFSET);
```

NMI is part of hardirq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How does Linux know what type of interrupt a specific one is?

Linux is using bit masks to isolate preempt, softirq, hardirq, and nmi interrupts. Looking at the [code where this is mapped out](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/79ef0c00142519bc34e1341447f3797436cc48bf/include/linux/preempt.h#L14), we find they stack on top of each other.

The lowest 8 bits are for preempt mask, above that another 8 for software irq. Stacked on top of that is hardware irq and finally the nmi mask.

### So what is NMI_OFFSET + HARDIRQ_OFFSET doing?

```
NMI_OFFSET + HARDIRQ_OFFSET = 1048576 + 65536 = 1114112 = 100010000000000000000
```

We have the offset now. This will be used to allow nested NMI interrupts. Each new NMI can be identified by adding one to this offset to go to the next.

### NMI is part of hardirq?

NMI are hardware interrupts, but not all hardware interrupts are NMI.

### Where can I read more?

The [core api entry documentation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/f400bea2d44beec76f7e7f45e5372ef790336a4d/Documentation/core-api/entry.rst) is a guide to kernel hackers.